# Invisible compilation errors in running developing an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Trying to run my eclipse plugin from within eclipse, I get error messages to the console, which make the nested eclipse fail to run the plugin:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:590)
...
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved
The import org.osgi cannot be resolved
AbstractUIPlugin cannot be resolved to a type
IStartup cannot be resolved to a type
The method earlyStartup() of type Plugin must override or implement a supertype method
BundleContext cannot be resolved to a type
BundleContext cannot be resolved to a type
```

Suggesting that my plugin has compilation errors to it, but:

- The plugin has not compilation errors
- It seems a bit surprising that running a plugin would cause a compilation.

Comment: Can you show us that it doesn't have compilation errors?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The problems view is clean, except for 30 something warnings (I try to raise ALL warning flags).

Comment: Are you certain that the **Problems** View isn't filtering out the applicable ones?

Comment: 100% so. I spend my time hunting down warnings and errors, so this could not happen, but I double checked. No.

Comment: Found the problem: nothing related to compilation errors at all! It was a `static` field which I used globally. Classloader loaded the class, but did not instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed no compilation error: the problem lies elsewhere. The main 
Plugin class was to be a singleton, which was implemented like so:

```
public class Plugin extends AbstractUIPlugin implements IStartup {
  public static Plugin plugin;
  / ** an empty c'tor. creates an instance of the plugin. */
  public Plugin() {
    plugin = this;
  }
  ....
}
```

Now, other classes were referring to this `public` field, which not initialized; for some reason, eclipse thought this was a compilation
error. It was not. using a getter for that field solved the problem.